# getting strange accuracy 1 on KNeighborsClassifier

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
knn_clf = KNeighborsClassifier(weights="distance")
pipeline = make_pipeline(scaler, knn_clf)

param_grid = {"kneighborsclassifier__n_neighbors": np.arange(1,11)}
knn_gscv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, cv=5, scoring="accuracy")
knn_gscv.fit(X_train, y_train)

knn_gscv.best_params_
knn_gscv.best_score_
print(knn_gscv.cv_results_)

y_pred_test = knn_gscv.predict(X_test)
y_pred_train = knn_gscv.predict(X_train)
print("train accuracy :", metrics.accuracy_score(y_train, y_pred_train))
print("test accuracy :", metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred_test))
```

Test accuracy looks reasonable (~90%), but train accuracy keeps giving me 1 which makes no sense, right?  It should be similar to knn_gscv.best_score_ which returns also reasonable number around 90% a bit higher than test accuracy.  What's going on here?

Comment: What is the selected `n_neighbors`?

Comment: 9 neighbors, so I'm not sure if 1 is possible

Comment: 9 is large enough to be surprising. What's the size of the dataset, and what's the class distribution?

Comment: 47000, distribution 42000 vs 5000

Comment: It is 100 variables so m.b points are very sparse and identity measurement has the most weight?

Answer (score 1):

`best_score_` is the accuracy in the cross-validation of the search, so it is measured on test folds. In that sense it should be closer to a test score; but also it has a selection bias to it. So generally you expect
`train_score > best_score_ > test_score`

With k-neighbors specifically, and especially with small `n_neighbors`, training scores are large because each point is its own closest neighbor, giving one free vote for the correct answer.  When `n_neighbors=1`, unless you have some duplicate points with different target values, you are guaranteed perfect training accuracy.

Comment: This makes sense but it selected 9 neighbors so that seems suspicious...